# Laravel:Redirecting to a page from a view that is sent to an email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, email

i am sending email to the admin that a user is waiting to be registered. and a button named activate user and after clicking this button it will redirect to a page or form.how can i do that in laravel? let this is my simple code

```
<p>A User is waiting to be registered!!</p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" method="post" 
redirect="{{ url('www.gmail.com')}}">
                                activate user
                            </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url('www.gmail.com')}}'">activate user</button>
```

Comment: tried this..not working..a button is showing but after clicking nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Create a view having the desired email's content:

```
// registered.blade.php
<p>A User is waiting to be registered!!</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('www.gmail.com')}}">Activate user</button>
```

Then send the email:

```
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    Mail::send('registered', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

        $m->to('admin@example.com', 'The admin')->subject('New user registered!');
    });
```

Comment: i am doing this...the code i wrote is in a view named emailMessage.blade.php and i am sending it from controller